# How does the Necromancy wizard's Inured to Undeath feature work with the Death Curse in the Tomb of Annihilation adventure?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, published-adventures, necromancy, tomb-of-annihilation

I am running *Tomb of Annihilation* for a group of players. They all wanted to bring in older characters (levels 9-11) from another campaign we had run a while back.

I did not allow the players to look at the book beforehand, but one of them went online and looked up the death curse. His character had died, so he rolled a new one. He decided to play a Wizard of the School of Necromancy, who has the Inured to Undeath feature starting at level 10:

> Beginning at 10th level, you have resistance to necrotic damage, and your hit point maximum can't be reduced. You have spent so much time dealing with undead and the forces that animate them that you have become inured to some of their worst effects.

Does the Inured to Undeath feature prevent him from being affected by the Death Curse? Or does the Curse work because it is a plot device?

Should I allow him to be the only party member who happens to be immune to the curse, or is this a god-level curse, meaning he can't avoid it?

Answer (score 21):

The curse still works. This character will simply never be in the position of having had their HP maximum reduced, and so won't suffer from the Death Curse's prevention of recovering from max-HP reduction.

If this character had even been resurrected/raised previously--and you indicate they haven't--they would be immune to the 1hp-max per day decline in well-being.

But if they die, there's no bringing them back. Like everyone else.

Comment: Doesn't this sort of go against specific over general? Of course that begs the question which is more specific, a single module that may or may not be used or a class feature presumably available to anyone?

Comment: @Slagmoth I think specific vs. general is an inappropriate lens to use here: the two rules aren't in conflict. One says that *if* HP-max-reduction happens, *then* it's not recovered as usual. Another says that HP-max-reduction won't happen. No conflict, to my mind.